Installing g++ and #include <iostream>
Here is what I installed

This told me that I had not installed g++ on MYS32

I finally managed to get g++ (but not in my VSCode console)

You just had to change the path in the settings

But there was always an error for my inputs outputs

Here is the error :
"#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (C:\Users\Olivier Robert\OneDrive\Images\Documents\Apprentissage de C++\Exercice_1.cpp).C/C++(1696)
cannot open source file "iostream". Please run the 'Select IntelliSense Configuration...' command to locate your system headers.C/C++"
I tried to modify it directly in the JSON but it still didn't work. Maybe it's not the right path or the right place

Would you know how to resolve this problem ?
Everything I did is described above

This is a question about configuring INCLUDE path for GCC or G++. Try some of these commands. I can't find Windows instructions for configuring G++ but the Ubuntu instructions might help.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

Problem is that VS code is not beginners friendly (especially when it should be configured at the beginning). This error you show on screenshot. Is this result of compiling from VScode or some plugin tries to parse code and show problems in advance.

Side note: Too many tools still up when there are spaces in paths. I strongly recommend avoiding them like the plague. "Olivier Robert" will cause you all sorts of troubles.

A plugin tries to analyze the code and show errors in advance. I did HTML, CSS, JS, React before but I decided to get into C++ a bit (I have exercises to do)
Finally, I downloaded VisualStudio Community 2022 by checking "C++" hoping that it works

VS Community is usually a much better choice when you're getting started. You don't want to be constantly second guessing, "Is this a bug or did I smurf up the IDE configuration again?"
